# Как связать навигационные вкладки с картой объекта svg?

Tags: wordpress

Есть карта объекта в формате .jpeg и отрисованные в svg каждый блок объекта, с подсветкой каждого соответственно. Рядом есть меню навигации (табы), которые при клике показывают информацию о каждом блоке.
Задача такова, чтобы при клике показывалась не только информация, но и подсвечивалась на карте объекта.[image: Интерактивная карта]

Comment: как svg вставлена, разметку добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @StrangerintheQ - <div class="map">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 199.36 327.67999">
   <path class="part" d="m 39.896181,76.55087 ..." fill="#d21e1e" id="stat"></path></svg>
<img src="http://www.example.ru/map.jpg" alt="">